# Sonata Admin: Multiple list tables in one page

Tags: symfony, sonata

I`ve 3 entities: Project, Campaign and AdGroupId (Adwords project) and they have One To Many relations: Project => Campaign => AdGroupId.
In Project list I added custom button, which redirects to Campaign list and shows all Campaigns by Project id. Campaign have same button for AdGroups.
Is it possible to show Campaign list table just below Project list table by pressing on button and same for adgroup (3rd list table below Campaigns)?

Comment: In sonata's structure it would be very complex like override list template then override table row template and then for each row get associations(campaigns) and display custom table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.

**Option 1 Sonata Blocks**

You can build your own blocks and use sonata admin as part of a block: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Then you can have a block that renders Projects list and add it to the Campaign list view or the other way around.

**Option 2 Ajax**

Sonata admin views and controllers are designed to be loaded and work well with ajax. On a ajax call they have a different render. You can have a look as an alternative to the sonata blocks.

Comment: How do you actually do option 1). You said "use sonata admin" as part of the block, but this isn't exactly straight forward. How would you tell the Block whcih admin class to render. Let's assume you get the admin from the pool... then what?